# SH process is using 50% of CPU, why is that?

Tags: shell

I have CRON running every 30 seconds, but that would fall under the `crond` process correct? Why is `sh` command sucking up 50% of my CPU when no one is running a Shell Script?

Comment: Best of my knowledge, you can't run a cron job at any smaller granularity than 1 minute.   Are you doing something special?  *how many* of the cron jobs are running?  Maybe it got loose and many are consuming your cpu? (all named similarly so you might not notice only the PID changing)

Answer (score 3):

Cron will run the command specified in the command field using `sh -c`. You can specify another shell by setting SHELL in the crontab file.

EDIT:

Just to clarify, the `sh -c` command will be ran as a subprocess of cron, which may spawn other subprocesses depending on the command given.

Answer (score 0):

`crond` runs as root on every system I'm familiar with:

```
1016 % ps -ef | grep crond 
root       342     1  0 12:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/crond
```

That's on a fairly current Arch installation, but an elderly Slackware says the same thing.  If you as some non-root user puts together a crontab file, `crond` will run the commands as your non-root user ID.  The root ownership has been a cause of several major security problems over the years.

As far as using 50% of a CPU, running something heavyweight every 30 seconds could easily consume 50% of a CPU.  Lots of "globbing" could do that, I'd think, as could doing a lot of sh-builtin string pattern matching or arithmetic.

Comment: Or it could be consuming 100% of a single core on a dual-core machine...